# How can I preserve generics on a React higher-order component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

Let's say I want to use the React [higher-order component pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to transform a subset of my props before they hit my component:

```
type UpstreamProps<X> = {
    foo?: number
    bar?: string
    baz:  X
}

type DownstreamProps<X> = {
    foo: number
    bar: string
    baz: X
    bix: string
}

function transform<X>(props: UpstreamProps<X>): DownstreamProps<X> {
    return {
        ...props,
        foo: props.foo || 0,
        bar: props.bar || '(unknown)',
        bix: `${props.foo}-${props.bar}-bix`
    }
}
```

At the widget definition, I want to use downstream (strict) props:

```
function Parent<X>(props: DownstreamProps<X> & {formatter: (x: X) => string}) {
    return (
        <>
            foo = {props.foo}
            bar = {props.bar}
            baz = {props.formatter(props.baz)}
            bix = {props.bix}
        </>
    )
}
```

At the call site, I should be able to pass in upstream (optional) props:

```
<WrappedParent<number>
    baz={22}
    formatter={(x: number) => `my number squared is ${Math.pow(x, 2)}`}
/>
```

This is as close as I've gotten to writing the higher-order component, but I can't get it to play well with the generics on the `Parent`/`WrappedParent`:

```
function withUpstreamProps<X, OtherProps>(
    WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<DownstreamProps<X> & OtherProps>
) {
    return function({foo, bar, baz, ...otherProps}: UpstreamProps<X> & OtherProps) {
        return (
            <WrappedComponent
                {...otherProps}
                {...transform({foo, bar, baz})}
            />
        )
    }
}

export default withUpstreamProps(Parent) // doesn't keep generics
```

There are two requirements here that are difficult to reconcile:

1. `withUpstreamProps(someRandomComponent)` should be an error. `withUpstreamProps` should only accept a valid component as an argument; i.e., one that accepts a superset of `DownstreamProps<X>`.
2. The emitted `WrappedParent` should be parameterized by one generic parameter; e.g. `WrappedParent<number>`.

How can I write and/or use my higher-order component wrapper to meet these requirements?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the generic type to the resulting component, the function returned from the HOC should be generic and take the `X` type as an argument and then pass it to `WrappedComponent`.

```
function withUpstreamProps(
  WrappedComponent: React.FunctionalComponent
) {
  return function <X, OtherProps>({
    foo,
    bar,
    baz,
    ...otherProps
  }: UpstreamProps<X> & OtherProps) {
    return (
      <WrappedComponent<X> {...otherProps} {...transform({ foo, bar, baz })} />
    );
  };
}
```

The `OtherProps` type should be passed too, so the `WrappedParent` would recognize the `formatter` function.

You should also assign a type for the `formatter` function when using the resulting component (`WrappedParent`)

Comment: Thank you @Yahya, but I need to be able to pass in the generic when I *call* the `WrappedParent`, so I can do both `<WrappedParent baz={22} formatter={(x: number) => \`${x + 1}\`} />` and `<WrappedParent baz='cow' formatter={(x: string) => \`${cow}bell\`} />`. I believe your solution would only allow `WrappedParent` to ever accept a number.

Comment: I just edited my answer, I hope it is helpful now.

Comment: This doesn't actually compile for me as `WrappedComponent` is not generic and can't accept the `<X>` argument. Additionally, even if it could, the way it is defined here means that `withDownstreamProps` is no longer typesafe; it could be called with any component as an argument, not just ones that accept `DownstreamProps<X>`. But I think you've hit on the central difficulty -- I'm not able to simultaneously define the outside generic on the wrapper and the inside generic on the wrapped component.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like that work for your case?:

```
type Wrapped<X, Other> = React.ComponentType<Output<X> & Other>

function withUpstreamProps<C extends Wrapped<any, any>>(
    WrappedComponent: C
) {
    return function<X, OtherProps>({foo, bar, baz, ...otherProps}: Input<X> & OtherProps) {
        return (
            <WrappedComponent
                {...otherProps}
                {...transform({foo, bar, baz})}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be on the right track but doesn't compile for me -- I've reproduced it [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpnOBw) if you're interested in fiddling with it. It also requires my wrapped component to take two generic args; the goal is for it to take only one, if possible, as in the original question, because the `OtherProps` are defined on the wrapped component itself and shouldn't have to be specified as a generic.